# Show images in slider from acf repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, repeater

I'm trying to show the ACF repeater image in the dynamic slider in oxygen via the PHP function from the specified page id.

ACF field: slajder
Subfield with img repeater: obraz_slajdera
Page id: 7219

I always get background-img unknown.
My code:

```
function get_slider() {
    $image = get_field( 'img', 7219 )['sizes']['large'];
    return $image;
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do some reading through the ACF developer documentation, your code is fragmented, and the **get_field()** function isn't being used properly. At any rate, I'll do my best to explain what you should be directing your solution towards. You'll first need to loop through your repeater fields, check to see if there's any "rows" in the repeater field, fetch your value, and then do whatever you need to do with your respective image.

So, technically your function should look something like this:

```
function fetchSliderImages() {

//Empty array for holding your slider images, assuming there's more than one
$sliderImages = array();

//Check to see if the slider even has rows
if( have_rows('slajder') ):

    //Loop through all the rows of your slider
    while( have_rows('slajder') ) : the_row();

        //Assuming this is coming back as a URL (can be adjusted within ACF)
        $imageRepeaterValue = get_sub_field('obraz_slajdera');

        //Check to see that we actually got something back that isn't blank
        if($imageRepeaterValue != '') {
            array_push($sliderImages, $imageRepeaterValue);
        }

    endwhile;
endif;

return $sliderImages;

}
```

You can then use this function to return an array of URL's which are slider images.

Used this for reference: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Comment: get_field() was my bad. I used your code, I set my slider to phpfunction 'fetchSliderImages' but now I'm getting: background-image: url(Array) :(

Comment: here is the [link](https://simpleframe.fisite.pl/blog/), images should be on hero slider